# How to recursive replace an element with value from 2 columns of previous row

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set of the following:

```r
Id   Val1  Val2
ID1  3     12  
ID1  4     NA  
ID1  -2    NA  
ID1  4     33  
ID2  4     NA
```

I want to replace the `NA` with `Val1+Val2` from the previous row if the `Id` is the same. The following is the ideal output:

```r
Id   Val1  Val2
ID1  3     12  
ID1  4     15  
ID1  -2    19  
ID1  4     33  
ID2  4     NA
```

I have a very big dataset. I personally don’t like the for loop in r and am looking for a beautiful vectorization solutions.

Comment: Can you please change the format of the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option where we group by 'Id' and a group created by taking the cumulative sum of logical vector i.e. where there are no missing values in 'Val2', then add (`+`) the `first` element of 'Val2' with the `cumsum` of 'Val1', take the `lag`, `ungroup` and remove the temporary 'grp' column

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Id, grp = cumsum(!is.na(Val2))) %>%
   mutate(Val2 =  lag(first(Val2) + cumsum(Val1), default = first(Val2))) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  Id     Val1  Val2
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 ID1       3    12
#2 ID1       4    15
#3 ID1      -2    19
#4 ID1       4    33
#5 ID2       4    NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("ID1", 
"ID2"), class = "factor"), Val1 = c(3, 4, -2, 4, 4), Val2 = c(12, 
NA, NA, 33, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```